# Evaluation of a polynomial over the finite field $\mathrm{GF}\left(2^{8}\right).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields, cryptography

I am trying to make a program that, among other things, considers a polynomial $p$ whose coefficients are elements of $\mathrm{GF}\left(2^{8}\right)$ and shows the user the graph of that polynomial. This necessarily implies that I must calculate the image of some numbers $\alpha_{1}$, $\alpha_{2}$, $\ldots$, $\alpha_{n - 1}$ and $\alpha_{n}$ under $p$, and this is where my confusion starts: to which set must $\alpha_{k}$ belong (with $k \in \left[1, n\right] \cap \mathbb{Z}$)?

In order not to have problems when performing the calculations, I could consider that all these $\alpha_{k}$ belong to the set $\mathrm{GF}\left(2^{8}\right)$, since, in this case, expressions like $$ \left[00000111\right]_2 \alpha_{1}^{2} + \left[00001010\right]_2 \alpha_{1} + \left[00000001\right]_2$$ would be well defined. But does it necessarily have to be so? Can't it be possible that $\alpha_{k}$ is some element of $\mathbb{R}$? And if it is possible, how should sum and product be defined so that expressions like the one I wrote make sense for values like $0.5$?

I apologize in advance if my doubt is nonsense. I have very little knowledge about finite fields, as all I know about them is due to the program I am trying to do, and, it is funny, but in all the files and videos in which I consulted about this question, nobody explains how the heck to perform the evaluation of a polynomial that belongs to $\mathrm{GF}\left(2^{8}\right)\left[x\right]$.

I deeply appreciate any answers you can offer me.

Comment: I think your confusion starts with the definition of $\mathrm{GF}(2^8)$. There is no relationship between this field and $\mathbb{R}$, so how are you going to graph any function? Just create a 256-by-256 sheet of paper with one dot in each column? Start with the field with four elements first and you will see the problem. In general, doing arithmetic in finite fields is non-trivial.

Comment: It is something I am asked to do. I don't know if this information is relevant, but my question arises from trying to do the following exercise:

“Using the numbers described in the document https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf (the elements of $GF(2^8)$) in its sections 4.1 and 4.2, implement operations with polynomials with coefficients the numbers described there, and graph the
and graph the two polynomials and the result of their operations (…).”

Comment: This is a description of how to make finite fields. Given a prime $p$, find an irreducible polynomial $f$ over $GF(p)$ of degree $n$. Then all polynomials over $GF(p)$ of degree less than $n$ form a field, $GF(p^n)$. Addition is standard addition of polynomials, with the coefficients coming from $GF(p)$. Multiplication is standard multiplication of polynomials, then take the remainder upon division by $f$. If $p=2$ then polynomials are the same as strings of 0s and 1s, which label the coefficients, and addition is XOR. Multiplication is harder to describe like this, but then you divide by $f$.

Comment: Are you talking about the multiplication and addition tables?